# Retrieve Data From Database and display in HTML forms through AJAX in django

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, django-models, django-views

recently I'm working on blog application using django framework.Right now I dont know how to retrieve data from database through ajax in HTML form.For example if user wants to edit his own post the page will redirected to blog_post page along with his old published post.I want to set that published data to blog_post page.So whenever the user go for edit the post the published post would be already mentioned and user can edit them easily.

Here is my code,

blog_post.html

```
 {% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Clean Blog - Start Bootstrap Theme</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="{%  static 'vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom fonts for this template -->
    <link href="{%  static 'vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet'
          type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800'
          rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="{%  static 'css/clean-blog.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>

<!--- ---      Here is my ajax which I had tried ----- --- !>
{% for i in blogs %}
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
            setInterval(function () {
                $.ajax({
                type : "post",
                url : "{% url 'edit_post' %}",
                data: {
                    "blogger" : {{ i.blogger_name }},
                    "blog_title" : {{ i.blog_title }},
                    "blog_subtitle" : {{ i.blog_subtitle }},
                    "blog_content" : {{ i.blog_body }},
                    "blog_img" : {{ i.blog_baseimg }},
                },
                success : function(response){
                    console.log(response)
                    $("#name").html(response.blogger),
                    $("#email").html(response.blog_subtitle),
                    $("#message").html(response.blog_content),
                    $("#file").html(response.blog_img)
                }
            })
        },1000)
    })
</script>

{% endfor %}
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" id="mainNav">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index">Start Bootstrap</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false"
                aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            Menu
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="about">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="sample">Sample Post</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% if user.is_authenticated %}contact{% else %}login{% endif %}">Post Blog</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'logout_user' %}">@{{ user.email }}</a>{% else %}
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login / Register{% endif %}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<!-- Page Header -->
<header class="masthead">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
                <div class="page-heading">
                    <h1>Post Blog</h1>
                    <span class="subheading">Start Interacting with World</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

<!-- Main Content -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
            <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" method="post" action="{% url 'post_blog' %}" novalidate>
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
                        <label>Title</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name = "blog_title" placeholder="Blog Title" id="name" required
                               data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
                        <label>Sub Title</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="blog_subtitle" placeholder="Blog Subtitle" id="email" required
                               data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
                        <label>Content</label>
                        <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" name="blog_content" placeholder="Blog Content" id="message" required
                                  data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class = "control-group">
                    <div class = "form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
                        <label>Blog Image</label>
                        <input type="file" class = "form-control" name="blog_img" placeholder="Upload Image" required id="file"
                               data-validation-required-message = "Please Upload An Image">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div id="success"></div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="sendMessageButton">Send</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<hr>


<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<!-- Contact Form JavaScript -->
<script src="js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
<script src="js/contact_me.js"></script>

<!-- Custom scripts for this template -->
<script src="js/clean-blog.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

views.py function

```
def blog_details(request,user_slug,blog_slug):
    blog = get_object_or_404(BlogData,user_slug__user_slug = user_slug,blog_slug = blog_slug)
    return render(request,"sample.html",{'blog':blog})
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path,include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("",views.index, name = "index"),
    path("login/",views.login, name = "login"),
    path("about",views.about,name = "about"),
    path("sample",views.sample, name = "sample"),
    path("register",views.register,name = "register"),
    path("contact",views.post,name = "post"),
    path("post_blog",views.submit_post,name = "post_blog"),
    path("<slug:user_slug>/",views.about,name = "about"),
    path("<slug:user_slug>/<slug:slug>/edit",views.edit_post,name = "edit_post"),
    path("<slug:slug>/delete",views.delete_post,name = "delete_post"),
    path("<slug:user_slug>/<slug:blog_slug>/",views.blog_details,name = "blog_details"),
]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import reverse
from login.models import User
from django.utils.text import slugify

# Create your models here.
languages = ['eng','fra','spa','hin']

class BlogData(models.Model):
    blogger_name = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='blogger_name',null=False)
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    blog_title = models.TextField()
    blog_subtitle = models.TextField()
    blog_body = models.TextField()
    blog_baseimg = models.ImageField(upload_to='pics')
    blog_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200,db_index=True,unique=False)
    user_slug = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='users_slug')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        #print(self.user_slug)
        #return f"/blogs/{ self.blogger_name }/{self.blog_slug}/"
        return reverse('blog_details',args=[self.user_slug.user_slug,self.blog_slug])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.blog_title
```